# When player jumps, so does the enemies (both enemy and player share the same parent class)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem in my game.

I have two objects on stage that extends off the same class.

The thing is when the player jumps, the ground moves down and the enemy falls down since its got gravity in it.

```
    private function scrollStage():void
    {
        if (lastPosX != lastPosX)
        {
            canScrollStage = false;
        }
        else if (lastPosX == lastPosX)
        {
            canScrollStage = true;
        }

        if (canScrollStage)
        {
            if (rightKey)
            {
                lookingRight = true;
                if (canParallaxRight)
                {
                    //trees.x -=  0.6;
                    //sky.x -= 1.3;
                }
                else
                {
                    //sky.x -= 0.4;
                }                   



            }
            else if (leftKey)
            {
                lookingLeft = true;
                if (canParallaxLeft)
                {
                    //trees.x +=  0.6;
                //  sky.x += 1.3;
                }
                else
                {
                    //sky.x -= 0.4;
                }                   
            }
            else
            {
                //sky.x -= 0.4;
            }
            for (var b:int = 0; b < childrenOnStage; b++)
            {
                if (getChildAt(b).name == "enemy" || getChildAt(b).name == "enemyRed" || getChildAt(b).name == "knife" || getChildAt(b).name == "ground")
                {
                    getChildAt(b).x += (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - character.x;
                        //getChildAt(b).y += - character.y;
                }
            }

            //ground.x += (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - character.x;
        }
        else
        {
            //sky.x -=  0.8;
        }

        // do this last, everything moves around object

        lastPosX = character.x;

        // Set the camera coordinates to the char coordinates.
        //camera.x = -
        // Adjust the world position on the screen based on the camera position.
        //ground.x = -camera.x + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        camera.y = Math.round(character.y);


        for (var d:int = 0; d < childrenOnStage; d++)
        {
            if (getChildAt(d).name == "ground")
            {
                getChildAt(d).y = -camera.y  + stage.stageHeight;//+ (stage.stageHeight / 2);
            }

        }
        //ground.y = -camera.y + (stage.stageHeight / 2);

        character.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;

    }
```

camera.y = character.y;

So since they share the same class, the enemy tends to jump up, since the ground is being pushed down.

Any tips on how I can fix this, so the enemy goes down with the goblin?

Many are saying to move the character first, and then move the ground. 
Well please check this.

private function processMovement():void
        {

```
        if (upKey)
        {

            if (climbDontJump)
            {
                character.yV = 0;
                character.y -= 2;;

            }
            else
            {
                character.jumpUp();
            }
            //character.jumpUp();
        }



        if (attackKey)
        {
            if (rightKey)
            {
                canParallaxRight = false;
                canParallaxLeft = false;
            }
            else if (leftKey)
            {
                canParallaxRight = false;
                canParallaxLeft = false;
            }
            character.attack();
        }
        else
        if (defendKey)
        {
            if (rightKey)
            {
                canParallaxRight = false;
                canParallaxLeft = false;
            }
            else if (leftKey)
            {
                canParallaxRight = false;
                canParallaxLeft = false;
            }

            character.defend();
        }
        else
        if (rightKey)
        {
            character.moveRight();
            lookingRight = true;
            lookingLeft = false;
        }
        else
        if (leftKey)
        {
            lookingLeft = true;
            lookingRight = false;
            character.moveLeft();
        }



        if (!leftKey && !rightKey && !upKey &&!defendKey && !attackKey)
        {
            character.dontMove();
        }

    }
```

I am moving the character.

And then doesn't this code move the container?

```
        if (lastPosX != lastPosX)
        {
            canScrollStage = false;
        }
        else if (lastPosX == lastPosX)
        {
            canScrollStage = true;
        }
```

and these two have been done last

```
        lastPosX = character.x;
        character.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
```

Comment: For starters, don't go Planet Express and move the whole universe relative to your hero. Move your hero, and then translate the stage to keep him centered.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat What do you mean? 

I've added more code to show you.

Comment: The boat means that when the character jumps, decrease the character's y instead of increasing the ground's y. The fact that your character & enemies have the same parent class doesn't matter.

Comment: @VBCPP I decrease y velocity in the character class , and the ground goes down be'cause I want to have the v cam effect so players can access higher platforms

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your problem is to change your code so that the enemies and ground move downwards as the character jumps. Moynul, I also agree heartily with itcouldevenbeaboat, move the character normally and then position everything else accordingly.

Comment: sure go for it, I'll show you what to change from there

Comment: take a look please at the links. 
https://gist.github.com/Moynzy/11323381
https://gist.github.com/Moynzy/11323363
https://gist.github.com/Moynzy/11323326